# Can you use strong parameters and whitelist attributes together in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, strong-parameters

We're on Rails 3.  We'd like to switch to strong parameters through the [strong_parameters](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters) gem.

The documentation of the gem says that to use this gem, the following value needs to be changed from `true` to `false` in the `config/application.rb` file

```
config.active_record.whitelist_attributes = false
```

We have many models and controllers in our application.  Making this change means we have to migrate ALL our models and controllers to strong parameters?

Ideally we'd like to migrate gradually.  That is, start using strong parameters for the new models and controllers, and then gradually update all the models and controllers.

So can you use strong parameters for some models/controllers and whitelist attributes for others?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I just started doing this. My experience is that I can leave the auto-whitelist enabled:

```
config.active_record.whitelist_attributes = true
```

Then I need to explicitly disable the whitelist in models I'm migrating to strong params using `attr_protected`:

```
class Widget < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_protected # disable whitelist in this model
  include ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesProtection
  ...
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use both together. You can simply mixin the `ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesProtection` module to the models you want to migrate to strong parameters while keeping your whitelist via `attr_accessible` in other models. Just don't disable the whitelist default until you've made the complete cutover. In other words, don't set this

```
config.active_record.whitelist_attributes = false
```

until you've fully migrated over.